# Bins vs. Breaks

Tags: r

I'm new to coding (Particularly R) and wanted to know what the differences between

```
Breaks =
```

vs.

```
Bins()
```

are and in what scenarios you would use one over the other.

Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Comment: There are no such functions. Can you provide an example on which you see them being used?

Comment: could this be in `ggplot::geom_histogram()` ... ??

Answer (score 1):

If this is in relation to something like histograms in `ggplot2`, the `bins` arguments automatically stack your data into a set number of columns, whereas the `breaks` arguments specify where exactly that is. As an example, we can look at these two plots:

```
#### Automatically Separates into Bins ####
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 10)

#### Manually Inserts Breaks at Designated Spots ####
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,
                          6,7,8,9,10))
```

The first automatically got assigned 10 bins (columns) like below:

[image]

Since the data deals with decimal values and is bounded between 4.3 and 7.9, the second manual 10 breaks at numbers 1 to 10 (explicitly I'm saying "I want Sepal Length 1 to 10") doesn't end up looking the same:

[image]

If I want to set it at much more precise locations, I can do this instead with the `breaks` argument:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram(breaks=c(4.0,
                          4.3,
                          5.0,
                          5.3,
                          6.0,
                          6.3,
                          7.0,
                          7.3,
                          8.0))
```

[image]